# Func vs Function in VB

Tags: vb.net, lambda

Would anyone be able to tell me what is the difference between a `Func` and a `Function` in VB.

For instance see the following:

```
Dim F As Func(Of String) = Function() As String
                             Return "B"
                           End Function
Dim F2 = Function() As String
           Return "B"
         End Function
```

- `F` appears as a `Func(Of String)`
- `F2` as a `Function() As String`.

It looks like they do the same thing but given that the compiler sees them as having different types surely there must be a subtlity.

Best regards

Charles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Func(Of TResult)()` is a specific delegate with the name `Func`. It is a type declared inside the `System` namespace as follows:

```
Public Delegate Function Func(Of TResult)() As TResult
```

It could have been named differently. For instance:

```
Public Delegate Function MyParameterLessFunction(Of TResult)() As TResult
```

So `Func` is really just the name given to a delegate. Since the type of `F2` is not specified explicitly, VB does not know a name for this delegate. Is it `Func` or `MyParameterLessFunction` or something else? Instead, VB just displays its signature `Function() As String`, since `F2` does also fit a non-generic delegate declared as

```
Public Delegate Function AnonymousParameterLessStringFunction() As String
```

---

In your comment you use `.ToString()` on `F` and `F2`. This returns the run-time types, i.e., the types of the values assigned to these variables. These types can be different from the static types of these variables, i.e., the type given to the variable name. Let's make a little test

```
Imports System.Reflection

Module FuncVsFunction
    Dim F As Func(Of String) = Function() As String
                                   Return "B"
                               End Function
    Dim F2 = Function() As String
                 Return "B"
             End Function

    Sub Test()
        Console.WriteLine($"Run-time type of F:  {F.ToString()}")
        Console.WriteLine($"Run-time type of F2: {F2.ToString()}")

        Dim moduleType = GetType(FuncVsFunction)
        Dim fields As IEnumerable(Of FieldInfo) = moduleType _
            .GetMembers(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Static) _
            .OfType(Of FieldInfo)

        For Each member In fields
            Console.WriteLine($"Static type of {member.Name}: {member.FieldType.Name}")
        Next
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

It displays

```
Run-time type of F:  System.Func`1[System.String]
Run-time type of F2: VB$AnonymousDelegate_0`1[System.String]
Static type of F: System.Func`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
Static type of F2: System.Object
```

Note that `F2` is simply typed as `Object`. This is a surprise. I expected it to be a of a delegate type.

---

You also see this difference in the debugger. If you set a break point into the `Test` method and then hover over the `Dim` keywords of `F` and `F2`, a popup displays

```
'Dim of F (static type)
Delegate Function System.Func(Of Out TResult)() As String

'Dim of F2 (static type)
Class System.Object
```

If you hover over the variable names

```
'F (run-time type)
Method = {System.String _Lambda$__0-0()}

'F2 (run-time type)
<generated method>
```

For `F` you not only get type information but also the name of the generated method itself. Since `F2` is an Object, Visual Studio obviously does not dig as deep as for `F`.

Comment: Hi Olivier. I think that makes sense. If I run .ToString() on F and F2 I get: F=System.Func`1[System.String], F2=VB$AnonymousDelegate_0`1[System.String]. That would be consistent with F and F2 being both delegates with the same signature but with a different name. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> F appears as a Func(Of String) F2 as a Function() as string.

No, it doesn’t. In both cases the variable type is a delegate that’s equivalent to `Func(Of String)`. Look at the code carefully again – both declarations have two parts; the declaration itself:

```
Dim F As Func(Of String)
' and
Dim F2
```

… and the initialisation:

```
Function() As String
    Return "B"
End Function

' and

Function() As String
    Return "B"
End Function
```

As you can see, the initialisation is identical. Merely the declaration is different because we omitted the explicit variable type in the second case. Thanks to `Option Infer`, the compiler can infer it for us.

In fact, the VB language specification has this to say (§8.4.2):

> When an expression classified as a lambda method is reclassified as a value in a context where there is no target type (for example, `Dim x = Function(a As Integer, b As Integer) a + b`), the *type of the resulting expression is an anonymous delegate type equivalent to the signature of the lambda method*. [emphasis mine]

Finally, what, then, is the difference between `Func` and `Function`?

`Function` is a *keyword* that introduces a function – either anonymous function (lambda) as in your code, or a “normal” function having a name, as in this code:

```
Function F() As String
    Return "B"
End Function
```

`Func(Of T…)` on the other hand is a *generic type* for a delegate. A lambda or a delegate can be bound to a variable declared with a fitting `Func` type. This is happening in your code.

Comment: When I meant "function", I wasn't referring to the function keyword used when creating a new instance of the function, but rather, if you hover the mouse over F2, the compiler will tell you that it is of type "Function() as String", whereas if you hover the mouse over F, it will be of type "Func(Of String)". I agree that the instance of a lambda I provided is the same, but the compiler seems to have inferred a different type. Which is what I do not understand. I was under the impression that in both case, F and F2 would be pointers to a function.

Comment: @Charles That sounds like an IntelliSense error. I cannot test this now because I’m on Mac, where no proper VB compiler exists, and C# doesn’t allow assigning a lambda to an implicitly-typed variable (I’m actually slightly surprised that VB does, but there is no real reason against it). What the IDE probably wants to tell you is that the type of `F` is “something like a function”. However, there are only two types which correspond to “something like a function”. The first is a delegate (i.e. `Func(Of String)`). The second is a “method group”, and you cannot declare variables of that type.

Comment: @Charles Another thing, there’s no such thing as a “pointer to function” in VB. Granted, VB has the keyword `AddressOf` which converts from a method group to a delegate but that keyword is simply misleading and exists for historical reasons. Delegates and function pointers are very different beasts.

Answer (score 0):

`Func` is a delegate type - [System.Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx).

`Function` is a keyword used to create lambda expressions.

The above lambda expressions are of type [System.Linq.Expression(Of System.Func(Of String))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx) and are indeed implicitly convertible to the delegate type [Func(Of String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx).

The difference is that the expression is stored as an expression tree - describing the structure of the code. During the implicit conversion it is actually compiled into a delegate.

Comment: Hi Jan. I think your response is in substance the same a Konrad. Please see the comment I added to his response.